# Run application in other AppDomain in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, appdomain

I have an ASP.NET application in which 5 sub - apps are running. I want one sub application to run in the other domain. I tried creating a new AppDomain:

```
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");
```

When I try to retrieve FriendlyName by the following code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(domain.FriendlyName);
```

I got this error:

```
Cannot obtain fields or call methods on the instance of type 'System.AppDomain' because it is a proxy to a remote object.
```

Comment: Please avoid forcing tags into title. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: It is clearly written into that link that : "choose the ones that best describe your question" and this is what I have done. But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: That part was about choosing the right tags as metadata. Read further down. ;)

Comment: They're pointing out that the **tags** at the bottom of your question tell us that this is a question involving `asp.net`. We don't need you to repeat that information in the title of the question.

Comment: Agree :) I have removed ASP.NET from the tittle.

Comment: I actually would have liked asp.net int the title.  ticky tacky comments...  feels like work.

Comment: Define *sub apps* as if they were truly sub they'd be in their own `AppDomain` already.

Comment: sub apps means - I have a drop down list on the login page and have 5 data into it that is referred as 5 different app. Say for example if i select the first option and login, then application related to that option can be viewed. So when this application logs in then it should run in some different domain.

Comment: what you describe is just 5 different sites on the same box and a main site with a link for each one, so the question remains what do you mean by sub apps? how do you intend to interact with them? why do you want to split them in several appdomains?

Comment: You understood it well. As there are number of users in one of the site, i want a certain site to run in different domain, so that other sites so not get impacted.

Comment: @Aditi Your question is not specific enough. I can not reproduce your problem. Your two lines of code are they really consecutive? In which context (WebForm code-behind, MVC controler ...) are they called?

Comment: When we want to run an application in a specific domain, it is these 2 lines of code requried. But on the second line itself I am getting an error as mentioned.

Comment: @Aditi:- I think you really need to elaborate your problem as it is difficut to understand what problem you are facing currently!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting it correctly then you nned to write a visualizer for that. It's a plugin for Visual Studio to "visualize" any watch value and you can do whatever you want to do in there, instead of in your actual project code.

Comment: It will be great if you can give some references for the same.